# HTML/CSS Sticky Header With Jerky Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I have attached a snippet of my issue- basically I have a sticky header with parallax scrolling to be implemented later, it looks fine but when I scroll down the image immediately exhibits jerkiness. It's a classic Html sticky header with the css set to fixed and z-index = 999.

I would like for the scrolling to be smoother. I noticed that it's only the first bit of scrolling (through the google image in the snippet) that it is jerky, and not further down the page.

What do I need to do to make this process smoother to the end user?

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

let header = document.getElementById("myHeader");

let sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font: 400 15px/1.8 "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

.bgimg-1 {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/img_5d5b215d04389.png");
  min-height: 110%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h1>Decade3</h1>
</div>

<div class="bgimg-1"></div>


  <div style="color: #777;background-color:white;text-align:center;padding:50px 80px;text-align: justify;">

    <h3 style="text-align:center;">How can we help?</h3>
    <p>Cupcake ipsum dolor. Sit amet marshmallow topping cheesecake muffin. Halvah croissant candy canes bonbon candy. Apple pie jelly beans topping carrot cake danish tart cake cheesecake. Muffin danish chocolate soufflé pastry icing bonbon oat cake. Powder cake jujubes oat cake. Lemon drops tootsie roll marshmallow halvah carrot cake.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any parallax effect here? Are you asking why the content snaps up behind the header when first scrolled?

Comment: @turnip yea, sorry that should be the question. Will implement parallax later... and change the title for now.

Comment: What is the reason that you add and remove the fixed positioning? This is the reason that the content jumps behind the header. Could you not make the header fixed all the time and just add some padding to the top of the content div? Eg. https://jsfiddle.net/zw9c187b/1/

Comment: @Turnip thanks, that was a bit of code that I took from a tutorial online. It looks good now, except that the image is cut off by the header at the top now... Do you know how I can keep the `min-height` in the css at 100% and move the image below the header?